# Ms ACCESS: calculating past annual averages over varying date ranges

Tags: sql, ms-access

In a form on Ms ACCESS, a user can select a commodity (such as copper, nickel, etc.) from a list and a commodity price date from a list. **A trailing 12 month average commodity price should then be calculated.**

For example: the user selects Copper as commodity and February 1st 2010, 02/01/2010. I then want the average price to be calculated over the time period: [02/01/2009 - 02/01/2010].

I'm not sure how to write this in query form. This is the current incomplete code;

```
SELECT Avg(CommPrices.Price) AS Expr1, 
FROM CommPrices
WHERE (((CommPrices.Commodity)=[Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List243]))
AND CommPrices.DateComm = [Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List55];
```

List243 is the list of commodities the user can select from, list55 is the list of dates the user can select. All data is obtained from the table CommPrices.

**Note**: the earliest dates in the column DateComm is 01/01/2008. So if the user selects a date for example 02/01/2008, then calculating the average over the past 12 months before 02/01/2008 won't be possible. I do want the code to still calculate the average using the dates available. (in the example it would just be the average over the past month)

**Second Note**: the column DateComm only has monthly dates for the first day of every month (e.g 01/01/2008, 02/01/2008, 03/01/2008). The dates listed in list55 can refer to different days in the month (e.g 03/16/2009), in that case I want the code to still calculate the past 12 month average using the closest commodity dates possible. So if the user selects date 03/16/2009, I want the code to calculate the  12 month average for 03/01/2008 - 03/01/2009.

Comment: Do you want `CommPrices.DateComm BETWEEN DateAdd('yyyy', -1, [Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List55]) AND [Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List55]`

Comment: As an additional comment to the above *(correct)* answer: I very much prefer to use *modules,* with subroutines that obtain numbers from various places, then use those numbers as *parameters* to the query. It is very difficult to maintain code that directly includes references such as `[Forms]:[Some_Form]![Control12345]`. (Inevitably, *someone* changes the name of *something,* *somewhere,* and all-of-the-sudden things start breaking, and it can be quite difficult to *find* them!)

Comment: @HansUp - thank you, this definitely works. However, it does not completely work in this case:
User selects date 08/24/2015 - the code in this case calculates the annual average from 09/01/2014 till 08/01/2015, while I would like it to calculate the annual average from 08/01/2014-08/01/2015.

Comment: The user selects date 08/24/2015, but this date is not listed exactly in the list of commodity dates. So if the user selects 08/24/2015, the closest commodity price date to that date is 08/01/2015. I then want the code to calculate the past 12 month average commodity price from 08/01/2014-08/01/2015. The code above calculates it using 08/24/2015 as starting point (minus 12 - closest 09/01/2014), while it should be 08/01/2015, even though the user selected 08/24/2015. The confusion is in the fact that the user can select different dates that are not exactly in the column for commodity dates.

Comment: Does it matter about "closest date"? Doesn't `BETWEEN` handle that kind of logic for you?

Comment: It doesn't matter that much, it's just what the assignment was and this is sufficient.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "integer" months it would be:

```
SELECT 
    Avg(CommPrices.Price) AS AveragePrice, 
FROM 
    CommPrices
WHERE 
    CommPrices.Commodity=[Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List243]
    AND 
    CommPrices.DateComm = BETWEEN
        DateSerial(Year([Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List55]) - 1, Month([Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List55]), 1)
        AND
        DateSerial(Year([Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List55]), Month([Forms]![Tool Should Cost]![List55]), 1)
```